# PHP Codes are displaying in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code to fetch data from a database table:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">EMPLOYEES DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <td>NAME</td>
            <td>EMPLOYEES<br>NUMBER</td>
            <td>ADDRESS</td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        //the example of searching data with the sequence based on the field name
        //search.php
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
        mysql_select_db("db_psu_online");

        $order = "SELECT * FROM tb_income_statement_igp_fields";
        //order to search data
        //declare in the order variable

        $result = mysql_query($order);  
        //order executes the result is saved
        //in the variable of $result

        while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            echo("<tr><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[2]</td></tr>");
        }
    ?>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output of the code above is this:
[image]

I don't know why the characters: `"); } ?>`  are being printed.

Comment: Avoid using parenthesis when using echo. I wonder if it's related but just a tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saving the file with the extension `.php`? Is PHP installed and enabled on your server?

The answer to at least one of these is "no", because what you are seeing is the raw PHP output in the HTML - if you use the browser's View Source, you'd see that clearly.

Comment: i am using wampserver. How do i know if PHP is installed or not?

Comment: Save the file with a `.php` extension. "WAMP" stamds for "Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP", so you almost certainly have PHP enabled, but it only works on `.php` files unless specifically configured otherwise.